# An item cannot be active at more than one location if one of them is a fulfillment service location

Tags: php, laravel, api, shopify

I am getting error saying,

> An item cannot be active at more than one location if one of them is a
>   fulfillment service location for shopify inventory.

Actually I'm trying to update inventory to shopify using api.
I have two location in shopify. Below is thecode that I used to set inventory to shopify.

```
$data = array(
    "inventory_item_id" => (int)$inventory_item_id,
    "location_id" => (int)$location_id,
    "available" => (int)$int_qty,
);
$inventory_details = $config->InventoryLevel()->set($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the **inventory managed by** setting for the concened item. Most probably that setting would be configured as some fulfillment service and when stock update is made to such an item with a different location_id (not corresponding to the fulfillment service) then this error message will be thrown.

In order to resolve this, either change the setting to **Shopify** or send the appropriate location_id corresponding to the fulfillment service.

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf8ZR.png)